# Python: Importing Modules of Modules

Tags: python

I currently have the directory structure

```
- module
    - __init__.py
    - foo.py
    - bar.py
```

I want to use function definitions from both `foo.py` and `bar.py` so have written this:

```
import module

module.foo.fooFunction()
module.bar.barFunction()
```

However I am getting the error `'module' object has no attribute 'foo'`.
What is the problem here?

Comment: Is that `init.py` or `__init__.py`?, and what are it's contents?

Comment: Yep that was a typo, will edit it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first, it should be `__init__.py`, not `init.py`.  Now, `__init__.py` is what sets up your modules namespace.

if `__init__.py` is empty, then to use `fooFunction`, you'd need to import `foo` too.  It doesn't automatically get imported with `module`.:

```
 import module.foo
 module.foo.fooFunction()
```

If you don't like that, you could do:

```
# __init__.py
import foo
import bar

# script
import module
module.foo.fooFunction()
```

See what happened there?  Since `__init__.py` imports `foo`, when you `import module`, it in turn imports `foo` and `bar` into it's namespace.  So, when you go to access it in your script, `module` already has a `foo` submodule imported into it's namespace.

You can even import names directly into the module namespace from foo or bar:

```
# __init__.py
from foo import fooFunction

# script
import module
module.fooFunction()
```

Comment: Thank you, very well explained

Answer (score 0):

In the `__init__.py` file (note the underscores -- yours doesn't have them), you have to `import from` your submodules.

In `mymod/__init__.py`:

```
from mysubmod1 import f
from mysubmod2 import g
```

In `outside.py`:

```
from mymod import f, g
```

Answer (score 0):

Module is a parent folder only, not a real module. If **init**.py is empty, you have to do this:

import module.foo.

module.foo.foofunc()

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget the **'as'** Python keyword. For the scenario

```
- module
- __init__.py
- foo.py
- bar.py
```

Another solution is this:

```
import module.foo as someAlias

# this can then be called as
someAlias.fooFunction()
```

where someAlias could be be anything you choose. As you can see it is less verbose than writing out 'module.foo.fooFunction()'